# how to generate and show sparkline charts in img using php?

Tags: php, laravel, charts, cryptocurrency, sparklines

im using php and laravel to create a crypto currency website

i want to show currensies rate and a tiny chart (sparklines), exactly like `coinmarketcap.com` an the home page:

[image]

at this site, urls of images are like this:

```
https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1.png
```

**the question is:** are these images already stored as files on the server?
or are they querying at loading time and displaying on the page in img tag?

and in any case, can everybody guide me please?

Comment: Use Elixir: https://courses.poeticoding.com/p/build-a-cryptocurrency-dashboard-with-elixir-and-phoenix-liveview

Comment: unfortunately it cant help me

Answer (score 0):

To generate such a chart, you need the Sparkline PHP class: [davaxi version](https://github.com/davaxi/Sparkline) (generates PNG images) or [jxxe version](https://github.com/jxxe/sparkline) (generates SVG images)

I think these images are generated once every certain period of time because they are daily graphs (30 days, 7 days, 1 day).